# Cakephp XML HTTP server how to get the request from client

Tags: xml, api, http, cakephp

This is my codes:

```
public function client() {  
    App::uses('Xml', 'Utility');
    $conditions = array('conditions' => array('title' => 'The title'));

    App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
    $http = new HttpSocket();
    $xml_data = Xml::fromArray( $conditions, array('pretty'=>'true'));
    $xml_string = $xml_data->asXML();
    $response = $http->get('http://localhost/cakephp/xml/server', $xml_string);
    //echo $response->body;
    echo $response->code;

    $this->set('xml', $response->body);
    $this->set('x', $xml_string);
}

public function server() {
    $this->layout=false;
     $this->response->type('application/xml');
    if($this->request->is('get')){
        $conditionXml = Xml::toArray($this->request->input('Xml::build'));
        //debug($conditionXml['conditions']);
         $title = $conditionXml['conditions']['title'];
       $posts = $this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' =>array('Post.title ='=>$title)));

        $posts = Xml::fromArray(array('posts' => array('post' => $posts)), array('pretty'=>'true', 'format'=>'tags'));
        $posts=$posts->asXML();
        $this->set('posts', $posts );
    }
}
```

---

How can I get the `$xml_string` in `server`? Any ideas?

Comment: You're talking about an XML based REST server, right?

Answer (score 0):

In your `$http->get` call, you're passing the `$xml_string` as a parameter. You should be able to receive that in your `server` function simply by changing the declaration as follows:

```
public function server($xml_string) {
```

Note that there may be URL encoding issues to consider here; I've never worked with this sort of setup.